# ServiceStack Service OnUnsubscribe\OnSubscribe\OnConnect user DisplayName is wrong

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

In my service stack I have the following AuthRepository initialization:

```
var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

string hash;
string salt;
var pwd = "ValidPassword";

new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString(pwd, out hash, out salt);
userRep.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
{
    Id = 1,
    DisplayName = "CustomDisplayName",
    Email = "test@gmail.com",
    UserName = "CustomUserName",
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName",
    PasswordHash = hash,
    Salt = salt,
}, pwd);
```

And in the same service I have some Event handlers:

```
private void OnUnsubscribe(IEventSubscription obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.DisplayName + " has unsubbed\n");
}

private void OnSubscribe(IEventSubscription obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.DisplayName + " has subbed\n");
}

private void OnConnect(IEventSubscription obj, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.DisplayName + " has connected\n");
}
```

The thing is that my `obj.DisplayName` is CustomUserName instead of being CustomDisplayName (and `obj.UserName` is also CustomUserName). Is this how it should work? If yes - how can I change DisplayName? Currently I use default `CredentialsAuthProvider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Authenticated users the [ServerEvents feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) uses the `session.UserName` if it exists since it's unique, if one isn't defined it falls back to the users `DisplayName`.

You can use the `ServerEventsFeature.OnCreated()` custom hook to change the custom metadata returned to Server Events client, e.g. You can change the `displayName` returned with:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
{
    OnCreated = (sub, req) => {
        sub.Meta["displayName"] = req.GetSession().DisplayName;
    }
});
```